# progressbar with overlay text

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, makecell

I need to display the actual percentage value as an overlay to a progressbar. As you can see in the MWE, the only thing I get is to move it below the bar, but I want it inside the bar. Is this even possible, I did not find any clue in the documentation. Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{progressbar}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\cellset{\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.3}%
\setlength\extrarowheight{0pt}}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
foo & bar & 
\makecell{
    \progressbar[linecolor=blue, filledcolor=green]{0.6}\\
    \tiny{$60\%$}
} \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: resulting progress bar]

Answer (score 2):

This is the list of keys accepted by the package

- borderwidth
- heighta
- roundnessa
- heightr
- roundnessr
- width
- linecolor
- emptycolor
- filledcolor
- tickswidth
- ticksheight
- tickscolor
- subdivisions

None of which allows you to do what you want. A solution is just to slightly modify the `.sty` file directly

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{progressbar}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\cellset{\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.3}%
  \setlength\extrarowheight{0pt}}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
    foo & bar & 
    \makecell{
      \progressbar[linecolor=blue, filledcolor=green, label = \color{black}{\tiny{$60\%$}}]{0.6}     
    } \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to use this [new version](https://pastebin.com/49RHA0jR), just copy it to the local directory you have your code at, under the name `progressbar.sty`

Comment: both version work like a charm. this one is perfekt, thank you!

Comment: @Andieh Great! Happy to help

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer not to have a copy of the package lying around, you could for example manually place text above the progressbar using for example a combination of `\llap` and `\raisebox`, or the `picture` environment. Examples of both are shown below. Of course, this is less convenient than a proper interface in the package, as trial and error is needed to properly place the text.

By the way, note that you're using `\tiny` wrong, it is not a macro that takes an argument (like `\textit`), but a switch that influences all the following text in the same group (like `\itshape`). So you should use it as `{\tiny text}`, not `\tiny{text}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{progressbar}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|}
foo & bar & 
  \progressbar[linecolor=blue, filledcolor=green]{0.6}\llap{\raisebox{1.5pt}{\tiny$60\%$}\hspace{0.8cm}}  \\
foo & bar & 
  \progressbar[linecolor=blue, filledcolor=green]{0.6}%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(-35,1.5) {\tiny$60\%$}
   \end{picture}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for this answer. it's perfect if you don't want to change the .sty file directly.